# Only one checkbox to be checked at time

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Well may be is easy but how can I make only one checkbox to be checked at time? Here is my checkboxes

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" id="radio" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="3"> 3
</label>
```

And JS that I use for the animation on them

```
$(function() {

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        span.addClass('checked');
    }
    $(this).wrap(span).hide();
});

function doCheck() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
    }
}

function doDown() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
}

function doUp() {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
}
});
```

Currently I can check multiple checkboxes.
[Here is quick JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7q2y06fq/)

Comment: Dude, use radio then.

Comment: Well, I know that I can use radios but in for my purpose I must use checkbox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" />
```

Change your input to radio and edit the css for them to be square if you really want the checkbox style.
You can totally get it running with a javascript controlling how many are ticked, etc, etc, but if it already exists, there's no point in not using it / creating it from scratch ;)

For unchecking radios:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Mkde/

Comment: It's not about the style it's about radios can't be unchecked.. this means if the user click on radio he can't uncheck it..

Comment: @John They can. I added a fiddle to the answer, found it while searching for that. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mkde/

Comment: Well this is something new. Thank's!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code if want to persist using checkboxes otherwise its better to use radio button instead
**HTML**

```
<label class="checkbox-inline check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" id="radio" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="3"> 3
</label>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.check input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $('.check input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/xz9x7ebd/) for the demo

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  
    if(this.checked){
       $('[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" id="radio" value="1">1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="2">2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="3">3
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input[name="skills"]').on('change', function () {
        $('input[name="skills"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```